# Android Camera Pinch Zoom

Tags: android

I'm making an application that use the camera hardware. I'm trying to implementing pinch zoom in the cameraview but the zoom out is not working, just the zoom in. Here is my code:
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

```
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    int action = event.getAction();


    if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
            float mDist = getFingerSpacing(event);
        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && params.isZoomSupported()) {
            mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
            handleZoom(event, params);
        }
    } else {

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            handleFocus(event, params);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void handleZoom(MotionEvent event, Camera.Parameters params) {
    int maxZoom = params.getMaxZoom();
    int zoom = params.getZoom();
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    int currnetZoom = params.getZoom();
    float newDist = getFingerSpacing(event);
    float mDist = 0;
    if (newDist > mDist) {
        if (zoom < maxZoom)
            zoom++;
    } else if (newDist <= mDist) {

        if (zoom >= 0)
            zoom--;
    }
    mDist = newDist;
    params.setZoom(zoom);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void handleFocus(MotionEvent event, Camera.Parameters params) {
    int pointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
    int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(pointerId);

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

    List<String> supportedFocusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
    if (supportedFocusModes != null && supportedFocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
        mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean b, Camera camera) {

            }
        });
    }
}

/** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private float getFingerSpacing(MotionEvent event) {

    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}


    please I really need help. Thanks
```

Comment: that `float mDist = 0;
    if (newDist > mDist) {` could be a problem. You probably want to make `mDist` an instance member instead of a local variable

Comment: also, you could use the built in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32711975/zoom-camera2-preview-using-textureview