# In Android Camera2 API, how can I set up a custom image aspect ratio or resolution?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I want my Android app to use a custom aspect ratio or recorded width and height, roughly 16:3, to scan a barcode in a preview. I expect that the camera sensor would have to read out less pixels and would be faster in processing. But I have not found any working example for Camera2 API that plays with custom camera resolutions. Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to directly tell Camera2 API the desired resolution before the picture is being taken. However, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350451/using-camera2-api-with-imagereader) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797596/how-to-increase-the-quality-of-captured-image-using-camera-2-api-android).
You can create an instance of ImageReader with the desired width and height like so

```
  //the size of the ImageReader determines the output from the camera.
  private ImageReader mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, ImageFormat.YV12, 30);
```

This way you will save processing time and memory when looking for the barcode.