# Camera2 API - AF_STATE cannot reach any LOCKED status

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2, autofocus

From the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html#CONTROL_AF_STATE), and the [camera2basic example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic), **(This question is based heavily on this camera2basic example)**

In `captureCallback`, `captureStillPicture()` will be executed after `afState` reached a locked status, i.e. one of the below:

(1) CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED
(2) CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED

It works, if there is no zooming feature. in `captureCallback`, afState can always reach either of the above 2 state, therefore `captureStillPicutre` is always triggered.

However, after I implemented [zoom feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32711975/zoom-camera2-preview-using-textureview/47709735#47709735):

- If I take a picture first, and then zoom, and then try to take a picture again, the second trial **cannot reach the lock status. It remains in CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_FOCUSED.**
- If I zoom, and then take the first picture, **the first picture can be focused**. But if I try again (even without changing zoom level), the second trial cannot reach the lock status. It remains in CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_FOCUSED.
- If I do not zoom at all, all attempts can reach a locked status.

In addition, I observed that in my test case 2 (Zoom and take a first picture), the camera tried to focus by changing its focus distance (you can observe that the preview changes from blur to clear). But such phenomenon does not happen in second trial.

The code for camera2 is quite long, but you may still look at my code [here](https://gist.github.com/lsw19921030/1c4000a5af069ddb366705edd33ebeea).
When user taps the shutter button, `takePicture()` will be executed, and therefore `lockFocus()` and so on.

Much appreciated if someone can help!!

Comment: any solution now?

Comment: @GauravGupta No, but I found that the same problem does not exist in Google's [CameraView's demo](https://github.com/google/cameraview). But I don't know why.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for the link. you made my day.