# Why is zoom implemented differently in Camera2 API?

Tags: android

In my Android app, I am trying to implement camera zooming using Camera2 API. There are numerous examples on how to implement zoom using Camera2 API. One such example is mentioned at [Zoom Camera2 Preview using TextureView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32711975/zoom-camera2-preview-using-textureview). Here is the essential code snippet:

```
float maxZoom = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM));
currentZoom = adjustZoom(currentZoom, maxZoom);
Rect m = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);
Rect m1 = cropRectangleBasedOnZoom(m1, curZoom);
previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, m1);
...
```

This seems to work. However, the old Camera1 API has a simple method to set the zoom value. Why one has to go through the extra logic of adjusting a region in Camera2 API? Does the Camera2 logic results in better picture quality?

Also, is there a way to obtain the value of maximum optical zoom? Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Camera2, devices can support off-axis zoom, which is more flexible than the old API design.  That said, not all devices support that feature, and you can check if a device does via [SCALER_CROPPING_TYPE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SCALER_CROPPING_TYPE).

And in general, camera2 tries to tie all coordinates to the sensor active array, so it's always clear what part of the sensor is being considered, so it's a matter of consistency.

Optical zoom isn't supported via the crop region; it's strictly about digital zoom.  If optical zoom is supported by a device, it's via [AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS) and [LENS_FOCAL_LENGTH](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#LENS_FOCAL_LENGTH).