# How to zoom camera using android camera2 API

Tags: android, zooming, android-camera2

I m using Camera2 Api for my app. I have a zoom in out function. I am able to zoom in and zoom out using pinch gesture. But how do I implement the same using a seekbar.

Comment: post your current code plz

Comment: Basically I followed this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32711975/zoom-camera2-preview-using-textureview

Answer (score 1):

The code to zoom:

```
int mProgress;
{
    minZoom = getMinZoom();
    maxZoom = getMaxZoom() - 1;
    final int zoomStep = 1;

    seekBarCardZoom.setMax(Math.round(maxZoom - minZoom));
    seekBarCardZoom.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
            new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    setCurrentZoom(Math.round(minZoom + (mProgress * zoomStep)));//not tested
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    setCurrentZoom(Math.round(minZoom + (progress * zoomStep)));
                    if(fromUser) mProgress = progress;
                }
            }
    );
}
```

And used this code in my CameraManager which extends BaseCameraManager:

```
@Override
public float getCurrentZoom() {
    return zoomLevel;
}

@Override
public void setCurrentZoom(float zoomLevel) {
    Rect zoomRect = getZoomRect(zoomLevel);
    if(zoomRect != null) {
        try {
            //you can try to add the synchronized object here 
            previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, zoomRect);
            captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequestBuilder.build(), captureCallback, backgroundHandler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error updating preview: ", e);
        }
        this.zoomLevel = (int) zoomLevel;
    }
}

private Rect getZoomRect(float zoomLevel) {
    try {
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(this.currentCameraId);
        float maxZoom = (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM)) * 10;
        Rect activeRect = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);
        if((zoomLevel <= maxZoom) && (zoomLevel > 1)) {
            int minW = (int) (activeRect.width() / maxZoom);
            int minH = (int) (activeRect.height() / maxZoom);
            int difW = activeRect.width() - minW;
            int difH = activeRect.height() - minH;
            int cropW = difW / 100 * (int) zoomLevel;
            int cropH = difH / 100 * (int) zoomLevel;
            cropW -= cropW & 3;
            cropH -= cropH & 3;
            return new Rect(cropW, cropH, activeRect.width() - cropW, activeRect.height() - cropH);
        } else if(zoomLevel == 0){
            return new Rect(0, 0, activeRect.width(), activeRect.height());
        }
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error during camera init");
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public float getMaxZoom() {
    try {
        return (manager.getCameraCharacteristics(this.currentCameraId).get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM)) * 10;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error during camera init");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: this code works fine when you gradually progress. But when you suddenly move to max or min its not working.

Comment: You can also try to add synchronized object which will prevent it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I  tested the code but I am still facing the same max zoom issue.

Comment: Did you try to add `synchronized` object to that place, which I commented in code?

Comment: @ZhebzhikBabich you mentioned extending the BaseCameraManager, but I cant find no such file. Is this a file you create on your own or is provided by the system itself ??

Comment: BaseCameraManager was get from https://github.com/memfis19/Annca library

Comment: Here is implementation of those classes:
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=memfis19/Annca/Annca-master/annca/src/main/java/io/github/memfis19/annca/internal/manager/impl/Camera1Manager.java#
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=memfis19/Annca/Annca-master/annca/src/main/java/io/github/memfis19/annca/internal/manager/impl/Camera2Manager.java#