# Is it possible to zoom cameraX or Camera2 beyond the Api max zoom limit

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-camerax

So I'm trying to make a binoculars/Telescope kind of app but the problem is I want to zoom to the max. I have seen there are apps on the store that does that but not sure how. I have tried cameraX linearZoom method but it only works in range between 0f - 1f Or is it possible to do this with Camera2 api? Any help would be highly appreciate. Please note I have only posted this queston after trying or researching different things for the whole day.

Thanks

Comment: Have you searched about "digital zooming"? Maybe that's good for your use case. Check for example this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52158395

Comment: @BrunoBieri yeah I know about digital zooming, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

For the curiosity of this question I decided to throw myself and try, the solution I found will not be the most conventional but it currently works.

After my first attempt I saw that it was not possible to increase the camera `max_zoom` so I thought of another way to enlarge what I was sending on the screen anyway.

My solution is based on the main layout in which you place the `textureView` in my case I decided to use a `LinearLayout`, that following some other guide i was able to zoom in by pinching it.

```
    public class ZoomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {

        private enum Mode {
            NONE,
            DRAG,
            ZOOM
        }

        private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1.0f;
        private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 10.0f;

        private Mode mode = Mode.NONE;
        private float scale = 1.0f;
        private float lastScaleFactor = 0f;

        private float startX = 0f;
        private float startY = 0f;

        private float dx = 0f;
        private float dy = 0f;
        private float prevDx = 0f;
        private float prevDy = 0f;

        public ZoomLinearLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init(context);
        }

        public ZoomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init(context);
        }

        public ZoomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            init(context);
        }

        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        public void init(Context context) {
            final ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, this);
            this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            if (scale > MIN_ZOOM) {
                                mode = Mode.DRAG;
                                startX = motionEvent.getX() - prevDx;
                                startY = motionEvent.getY() - prevDy;
                            }
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            if (mode == Mode.DRAG) {
                                dx = motionEvent.getX() - startX;
                                dy = motionEvent.getY() - startY;
                            }
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                            mode = Mode.ZOOM;
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                            mode = Mode.DRAG;
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            mode = Mode.NONE;
                            prevDx = dx;
                            prevDy = dy;
                            break;
                    }
                    scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

                    if ((mode == Mode.DRAG && scale >= MIN_ZOOM) || mode == Mode.ZOOM) {
                        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        float maxDx = (child().getWidth() - (child().getWidth() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
                        float maxDy = (child().getHeight() - (child().getHeight() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
                        dx = Math.min(Math.max(dx, -maxDx), maxDx);
                        dy = Math.min(Math.max(dy, -maxDy), maxDy);
                        applyScaleAndTranslation();
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
            float scaleFactor = scaleDetector.getScaleFactor();
            if (lastScaleFactor == 0 || (Math.signum(scaleFactor) == Math.signum(lastScaleFactor))) {
                scale *= scaleFactor;
                scale = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scale, MAX_ZOOM));
                lastScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
            } else {
                lastScaleFactor = 0;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
        }

        private void applyScaleAndTranslation() {
            child().setScaleX(scale);
            child().setScaleY(scale);
            child().setTranslationX(dx);
            child().setTranslationY(dy);
        }

        private View child() {
            return getChildAt(0);
        }

    }
```

What manages the maximum of our zoom is no longer the power of the camera but our variable `MAX_ZOOM` witch in our case is set to 10.0f (but you can actually change it).

The next step is to enclose the `TextureView` used in camera2 between the `ZoomLinearLayout`:

```
    <com.giacomociardini.zoom.ZoomLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000" />

    </com.giacomociardini.zoom.ZoomLinearLayout>
```

The `FrameLayout` is only a container for the fragment (the TextureView) that is in charge of all the hard work for the camera2, this is my final result:

[video](https://thumbs.gfycat.com/OldfashionedFatalCanine-mobile.mp4)

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9xOH.jpg)

Notice: the results are made by only zooming inside the view, if you combine it with the zoom of the camera you are gonna get a result way much smoother!

Comment: Thank you :) Actually, I'm looking to zoom in the camera, You're solution is good but not what I'm looking for. In your case it's only scaling the view, it will very quickly pixelate in case of distant zooming. Again thank you very much for putting in the effort. Really appreciate :)

Comment: You have any example of what you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well sort of you can download any binocular or telescope app, Like distant zooming but with better quality like not pixelating too much.

Comment: If you notice in your example the pixelation starts even the object in focus (paper) is very close to the camera.

Comment: In reality i did that example really quick and doesn't reflect what is really capable of (by combining the zoom of the camera with the zoom inside the view)..

Comment: Congratulation on winning the bounty. I appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do might not be very possible and is entirely dependent on the ability of the physical mobile camera unless the app's function is to automatically zoom in on an image taken by the onboard camera. Read the api documentation and see if the api allows the ability to zoom in further than usual on an android camera. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually the Api does have a limit but I want to zoom past that limit.

Comment: Can you send me the documentation? The documentation might mention limitations.